# Has the effort to confirm $\Sigma(5)$ and the search for new champions with $6$ states been stopped?

Tags: reference-request, turing-machines

Is there a site about recent new results about the busy beaver hunt for $5$ and $6$ states ? I wonder whether there are just no new results or if the search has been stopped.

In particular, I am interested in the machines with $5$ states that are officially open, and whether new champions for a $6$-state-machine are still searched.

Comment: [This mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212429/recent-progress-on-the-busy-beaver-problem) from 2015 discusses progress up to that point.

Comment: I have some interest in Busy Beavers as well, and was also wondering what the current status is, in particular which machines are still 'holdouts' (machines of which we currently don't know whether they halt or not); I saw some holdouts listed in some very old papers/websites, but can't confirm that anno 2018 they still are.  Here is [a question I asked on the Computer Science SE about this] (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78078/wanted-concrete-example-of-busy-beaver-holdout).  If you find out some more information yourself, please share :)